# Exist any way for running a WPF .NET Framework 4.5 project on Windows XP?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-xp

I have an WPF application that have .NET Framework 4.5 as Target Framwork. I would like that the application also run on Windows XP, but when I try to install the .NET Framework on Windows XP Service Pack 3, a message that said is not supported is showed. The question is:

Exist any way for running a WPF .NET Framework 4.5 project on Windows XP?

Comment: It is right, I don't know why SO don't suggest it when writing the question.